# Enums with pointers in struct definitions

Tags: python, c, pointers, enums, ctypes

I am working on creating access to a dynamic library in python using the ctypes module.  While duplicating some of the tydef'd structures in my python implementation I came across a bit of code that has me stumped as to what is happening.  Basically what I have is

```
enum foo {
    a,
    b,
    c,
};

typedef struct barStruct bar;

struct barStruct{
    enum foo (*lem)();
    enum foo (*baz)(bar *next);
}
```

in a header file.

I am trying to understand the two enum calls in the struct definition.  I thought that the first one was creating a pointer called `lem` which has to point to values contained in the enumeration (so I essentially ignored the open/close parenthesis at the end).  When I noticed the second one, with another pointer in the parenthesis, then I got really confused as to what is going on, and doubted my guess as to what the first one meant.

I apologize if this question already has an answer (which I'm sure it does) but unfortunately I cannot think of how to effectively search for what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those aren't "enum calls", those are declaring two members in the structure, members that are pointers to functions.

For example

```
enum foo (*lem)();
```

declares a structure member variable `lem` that is a pointer to a function taking an indeterminate number of arguments, and *returns* a `foo` enumeration.

Comment: oh, ok, that makes sense. So the second one is a pointer to a function returning a foo enum that inputs a pointer to a bar type struct, correct?